# Do I need any letter from my current Employer for German Business Visa (Job Interview Purpose)?

Tags: visas, business-travel, schengen-visas

I have a job interview in a German company and I got the invitation letter from them.

There is one required document for a Business Visa which is a letter from current employer or NOC from a current employer.

Since I am going to Germany for a Job interview, do I really need to get a NOC or any letter from my current Employer?

My Principle Investigator (PI) and the University will not give me any letter for the purpose of Job Interview, (why would they give me, it doesn't make any sense) so in that case, what document do I need to submit instead of NOC or current employer letter.

Comment: What country do you come from? Are you currently employed by the University or are you a student about to graduate?